# Prove there exist linear operator such that..

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T(1,1,1) = (1,1,1), T(0,1,0) = (0,1,0), T(1,0,2)=(1,0,1)$. Prove that there is a **unique** linear transformation and write the representing matrix in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$,${\left[ T \right]_{E \to E}}$.

**For the first question**: I checked and found that $\{(1,1,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,2)\}$ is linearly independent, and therefore is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I know that a linear transformation is determined uniquely by the terms of the basis. I'm not sure if this statement alone is suffice to prove uniqueness. What should I add to this claim?

**For the second demand**, Is the following right? is there a better way?
I was able to find ${M_{B \to E}}$. It's easy to calculate the inverse which is  ${\left[ {{M_{B \to E}}} \right]^{ - 1}} = {M_{E \to B}}$. 
We know also know what ${\left[ T \right]_B}$ is.

Now we can use the formula:
$${\left[ T \right]_E} = {M_{E \to B}}{\left[ T \right]_B}{M_{B \to E}}$$

I didn't write down calculations, because only the idea is important to me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes. If you know what each element of a basis is mapped to, this identifies a unique linear transformation. To see why, think about the following situation:

> Assume you have two linear transformations $T_1,T_2$ which each take elements of the ordered basis $\{b_1, \dots, b_n\}$ to the same elements in the codomain, then show that the same must hold for any vector in your space.

2) Yes, this is correct and is the normal way of doing it. Let's think about what your last line means. Take some $\alpha$ in your vector space. $E$ is the standard basis, and $B$ is the one that you're given:

$$[T]_E [\alpha]_{E}=M_{E\rightarrow B} \ [T]_B \ \ M_{B\rightarrow E} \ [\alpha]_E$$

First $M_{E\rightarrow B}$ acts on $[\alpha]_E$ so that it turns into $[\alpha]_B$. Then $[T]_B$ does its thing, and finally $M_{B\rightarrow E}$ takes it back into its representation under $E$.

Comment: http://memecrunch.com/meme/10JD7/give-that-man-a-cookie/image.png